# C math order of operation

Tags: c, math, operator-precedence

I have an assignment that I have been working on. My code appears to have the correct math operations and in the correct order (at least sequence wise), but my answers are a little screwy. I get parts of each question right according to my input values, but never the same part(s) as input values change. Is there something about C order of operations that I am missing that is causing this?

I feel like the problem is at

```
intPeople = intCarCounter * intTrainCounter * CAR_CAPACITY;
```

For sample run #3 I get 120 people for the first two inputs (exactly 20 more than the correct answers) and the surplus number is what should be in sample run #4. On the third input I get 112 people which is again the correct answer for sample run #4. Finally, on sample run #4 I get 128 people (16 more than the correct answer) and the surplus number is what should be in sample run #3. Any ideas?

Assignment:
http://cop3223.blogspot.com/2013/01/problem-c-roller-coaster-design-coasterc.html

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FIRST_CAR_LENGTH 10
#define NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH 8
#define CAR_CAPACITY 4

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize Variables */
    int intTrack,intMaxTrainSize,intActualTrainSize,intPeople,intCarCounter,intTrainCounter,n;

    /* Ask user for value of N */
    printf("What is the value for N?> ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        /* Ask user for total length of track */
        printf("\nWhat is the total length of the track, in feet?> ");
        scanf("%d",&intTrack);

        /* Ask user for maximum length of each train */
        printf("What is the maximum length of a train, in feet?> ");
        scanf("%d",&intMaxTrainSize);

        /* Set/Reset initial values of intActualTrainSize, intCarCounter and intTrainCounter */
        /* Each train will begin with FIRST_CAR_LENGTH -> intActualTrainSize=FIRST_CAR_LENGTH */
        /* Each train will begin with 1 car -> intCarCounter=1 */
        /* Train counter will begin at 0 -> intTrainCounter=0 */
        intActualTrainSize=FIRST_CAR_LENGTH;
        intCarCounter=1;
        intTrainCounter=0;

        /* Continue to add additional cars using NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH until the maximum train size has been reached */
        /* Count how many NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH cars are added -> intCarCounter++*/
        while (intActualTrainSize < intMaxTrainSize)
        {
            intActualTrainSize=intActualTrainSize+NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;
            intCarCounter++;
        } 

        /* Count how many trains can be added until 25% of the track is used up -> intTrainCounter++ */
        while (intTrainCounter*intActualTrainSize < (int)(intTrack*.25)) 
        {
            intTrainCounter++;
        }

        /* Count how many people can be on the track at one time -> intPeople = intCarCounter * intTrainCounter * CAR_CAPACITY */
        intPeople = intCarCounter * intTrainCounter * CAR_CAPACITY;
        printf("\nYour ride can have at most %d people on it at one time.",intPeople);

        if (intActualTrainSize>intMaxTrainSize)
            printf("\nMaximum Train Length has surplus of %d feet.\n",intActualTrainSize-intMaxTrainSize);
        else if (intMaxTrainSize==intActualTrainSize)
            printf("\nMaximum Length fits exactly.\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or printf statements at each step to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a loop to calcutate train counters and car counters, instead you could, as another alternative, use integer arithmetic to calculate those values. I have attached my solution which does not involve loops. It makes easier to debug. I am providing two versions. Version 1 sassumes integer division does no round-off. Version 2 is safer as it subtracts remainders before division.

```
    //VERSION 1:

    #include <stdio.h>

    #define FIRST_CAR_LENGTH 10
    #define NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH 8
    #define CAR_CAPACITY 4

    int main(void)
    {
      int N, i;
      int trackSize;
      int trainSize;
      int numberPeople;
      int numberCars;
      int trainsPerTrack;
      int surplus;

      printf("What is the value for N?");
      scanf("%d", &N);
      for(i=0; i < N; i++)
      {
         printf("What is the total length of the track, in feet?\n");
         scanf("%d", &trackSize);
         printf("What is the maximum length of a train, in feet?\n");
         scanf("%d", &trainSize);
         trainsPerTrack = trackSize / (4 * trainSize);
         numberCars = (trainSize -FIRST_CAR_LENGTH) / NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH + 1;

         numberPeople = trainsPerTrack * numberCars * CAR_CAPACITY;
         printf("Your ride can have at most %d people on it at one time.\n", numberPeople);

         surplus = (trainSize - FIRST_CAR_LENGTH) % NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;
         if(surplus)
           printf("Maximum Train Length has surplus of %d feet\n\n", surplus);
         else
           printf("Maximum Length fits exactly\n\n");
      }
      return 0;
    }


VERSION 2:
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST_CAR_LENGTH 10
#define NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH 8
#define CAR_CAPACITY 4

int main(void)
{
  int N, i;
  int trackSize;
  int trainSize;
  int numberPeople;
  int numberCars;
  int trainsPerTrack;
  int surplus;

  printf("What is the value for N?");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  for(i=0; i < N; i++)
  {
     printf("What is the total length of the track, in feet?\n");
     scanf("%d", &trackSize);
     printf("What is the maximum length of a train, in feet?\n");
     scanf("%d", &trainSize);
     trainsPerTrack = (trackSize- (trackSize % (4*trainSize))) / (4 * trainSize);
     int forSmallerCars = trainSize - FIRST_CAR_LENGTH;
     numberCars = (forSmallerCars - (forSmallerCars % NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH)) / NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH + 1;

     numberPeople = trainsPerTrack * numberCars * CAR_CAPACITY;
     printf("Your ride can have at most %d people on it at one time.\n", numberPeople);

     surplus = (trainSize - FIRST_CAR_LENGTH) % NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;
     if(surplus)
       printf("Maximum Train Length has surplus of %d feet\n\n", surplus);
     else
       printf("Maximum Length fits exactly\n\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. It is cleaner, faster, and the concept of integer math is a good fit for the problem. Does it give the right answers?

Comment: Agreed!! This also helped isolate the problems from above, apparently it all stemmed from the division operations. Depending on which compiler I was using it would either round up to the next integer if there as any remainder or, truncate the to the whole number portion. This is a self induced problem because I like to code in Visual Studio but my assignments must be tested with DevC++. I thought C would always truncate instead of round regardless of the coding environment. But apparently not!

Comment: I implemented version 2 and added to the source code above so you have both versions. In version 2 I get rid of rounding problem by subtracting the remainder(that could lead to rounding) before division. I think this is more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it directly contributes, but you need to recheck the below

```
while (intActualTrainSize +NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH  <= intMaxTrainSize )
{                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    intActualTrainSize=intActualTrainSize+NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;
    intCarCounter++;
}
```

Your code allows for Actual train size to overflow max train size, so that might be 10 of the extra 20. This check will ensure that you only add cars if it will STILL remain within the max.

**Similarly with Train counter**, which can also overflow.

**Try to convert such while loops into math formulas** if you can, more efficient and more readable.

Comment: Your answer is more complete than mine since you suggest how to code correctly while I only pointed out one mistake and you saw at least two. So +1 from me.

Comment: I see where you are going but if you subtract NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH from intMaxTrainSize, you are effectively shrinking the max train size. If I enter 42 feet as the max train size then I want to continue adding cars until I have met that length. But even with that said, intMaxTrainSize = intMaxTrainSize - NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH right after the loop still does nothing.

Comment: You are not shrinking the max train size at all, you are checking that after adding the train you will STILL BE under the max size.

Comment: @John since you only use the variable in that one loop, for the change to affect anything at all, you would need to make it BEFORE the loop, though I wouldnt do it since it is semantically wrong.

Comment: @John you can write `intActualTrainSize +NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH < intMaxTrainSize ` if that makes it clearer

Comment: ahh, derr!! you are correct. BTW I went with intActualTrainSize +NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH < intMaxTrainSize. Still no change on the output and now the last if statement isnt evaluated at all... due to intActualTrainSize never being assigned a value greater than or equal to intMaxTrainSize. I feel like I'm having more of an arithmetic issue than a logic issue.

Comment: @John thats the point of the last `if` isnt it? It will never hit because by definition, the Max is the Max..

Comment: @John surprising that output doest change.. Regardless, you need to fix the same issue with train counter as well.

Comment: Also, as part of the assignment I need to allow the value of intActualTrainSize to equal and or exceed intMaxTrainSize. In the case of it exceeding, I need to calculate the amount it exceeds intMaxTrainSize, and if intActualTrainSize equals intMaxTrainSize, then simply state that I have entered a length that can be achieved with an exact number of cars.

Comment: @John you missunderstand the question, You need to return if `intActualTrainSize<intMaxTrainSize`, not greater than.  "If the Maximum Length exceeds the Actual Length"

Comment: I think it has to be `<=` and not `< intMaxTrainSize`

Comment: Ok, after a good night sleep I had some progress... I changed the second while loop to "while ((intTrainCounter+1)*intActualTrainSize < (int)(intTrack*.25))" and the printf on the if now has printf("\nMaximum Train Length has surplus of %d feet.\n",NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH-(intActualTrainSize-intMaxTrainSize));

Comment: Now I get the correct surplus length for all sample run #3 and #4 values. I also get the correct number of people except when max train length is 49 or 59 in sample runs #3 and #4. When the length is 49 or 59 my program gives me 96 people for both but I should have 104 and 112 respectively (BTW those answers are over by 4 and 16 respectively)

Comment: Add some printf statements for debug. How many cars in each train? How many trains?  I suspect that you need another <= instead of < when you check how many trains fit - but I am reading this on iPhone and its a bit hard to check your code line by line...

Answer (score 0):

Your train ends up too long in the line that says

```
    while (intActualTrainSize < intMaxTrainSize)
    {
        intActualTrainSize=intActualTrainSize+NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;
        intCarCounter++;
    }
```

Since you will execute this loop until the train is too long...

Answer (score 0):

Type in variable names and one character variable names are not recommended. Incrementing a counter in a loop with a fix value is shipped with multiplication, no iteration needed. Actual train size exceeds maximum in last iteration of your loop. What if user provided max train size is under FIRST_CAR_LENGTH? Approachment of calculating actual train size first is right. Hassan's answer seems to be incorrect if surplus exists.

```
const double occ = 0.25;

int track;
int max_train;

int cap;
int num_car;
int num_train = 0;
int train = 0;

printf( "Length of track? "); scanf( "%d", &track );
printf( "Max length of train? "); scanf( "%d", &max_train );

num_car = std::max( 0, max_train - FIRST_CAR_LENGTH + NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH ) / NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;
if( 0 < num_car )
{
    train = FIRST_CAR_LENGTH + NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH * ( num_car - 1 );
    num_train = ( int ) ( occ * track ) / train;
}
cap = CAR_CAPACITY * num_car * num_train;
printf( "Capacity: %d; Train surplus: %d\n", cap, max_train - train );
```